# Construct a mapped type from an array of generic objects

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type which just adds an extra property to another type:

```
type ObjWithPath<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } & { _path: string }
```

I have a black box JS function I need to provide a return type for, which takes an array of this generic type as its parameter:

```
declare function blackBox(objs: ObjWithPath<any>[]): any; // <-- I'd like to create a return type given the array passed in
```

I know what structure the return type should have, but I'm struggling to see if this is possible, since it seems like there's no way to gain access to the generic parameters of the individual array elements and use them in creating a new type.

Given an input array with the following types

```
const startingArray: ObjWithPath<any>[] = [
    { _path: "hello", prompt: "World" }, // ObjWithPath<{prompt: string}>
    { _path: "foo", bar: 4 },            // ObjWithPath<{bar: number}>
    { _path: "testing", value: 123 },    // ObjWithPath<{value: number}>
]
```

The return type of the function is expected to be

```
{
  hello: { prompt: string },
  foo: { bar: number },
  testing: { value: number },
}
```

The goal being that with the returned object, I should be able to do this:

```
const returnObj = blackBox(startingArray)
console.log(returnObj.hello) // { prompt: "World" }
// or
console.log(returnObj["hello"]) // { prompt: "World" }
```

In other words, an object where the *keys* are the values of the `_path` properties of each array item, and the values have the type of the generic parameter of that array item.

I'm struggling on both parts of this requirement. I'm not sure if it's possible to use mapped type syntax to map the values of objects in an array to keys of another object, or maybe there is another mechanism that allows this? I also can't figure out how to actually get the generic paramter type of an individual array item. Is this type information even available?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ12gm) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your proposal is pretty good, but it looks like for the value objects of the return type, you are filtering their keys for everything that isn't "path".

I was hoping that there might be a way to preserve the underlying generic type. For example, if we had `ObjWIthPath<SomeInterface>` then we could infer the `SomeInterface` in the return type instead of a collection of k/v pairs mimicking it.

Comment: TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), not nominal, so those are effectively the same type.  I doubt there's any technique which will consistently return the *name* you want to see for a structurally identical type.  That feels offtopic here, in any case, since it would involve a digression about structural vs nominal typing.  May I proceed with this answer or do you want to [edit] the question to specify something additional about type naming so that we can say "sorry, it's impossible"?

Comment: @jcalz I should be able to use this to get what I need. You are using a few methods here that I haven't seen before so you may proceed with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the compiler to keep track of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `_path` properties of `startingArray` so that they can be used as keys of the value returned from `blackBox()`, as well as the types of each property, then you can't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as `ObjWithPath<any>[]` or even a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[ObjWithPath<{prompt: string}>, ObjWithPath<{bar: number}>, ObjWithPath<{value: number}>]`.  Annotating a variable with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type effectively throws away any more specific information from its initializer.

So for the first step, let's forgo annotating at all, and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) instead to ask the compiler to infer the most specific type it can for `startingArray`:

```
const startingArray = [
  { _path: "hello", prompt: "World" },
  { _path: "foo", bar: 4 },
  { _path: "testing", value: 123 },
] as const; // <-- need this or the complier has no idea what strings _path are

/* const startingArray: readonly [{
    readonly _path: "hello";
    readonly prompt: "World";
}, {
    readonly _path: "foo";
    readonly bar: 4;
}, {
    readonly _path: "testing";
    readonly value: 123;
}] */
```

That might be more information than you care about preserving, but at least now we can proceed.

---

Given that, we want to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) utility type to convert from an array of `ObjWithPath<?>`-compatible types to the type of the output object.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj<T extends readonly { _path: string }[]> =
  { [U in T[number] as U["_path"]]: Omit<U, "_path">}
```

This type [constrains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) its type parameter to be an array of objects with a string `_path` property (actually a [`readonly` array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), which accepts mutable arrays also).  And it uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to convert all array element types to key-value pairs.  Given an arraylike type `T`, the type `T[number]` is the union of the types of its elements (which is what you get if you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T` with a numeric key).  For each element `U` in that union, we want to use `U["_path"]` as the key (again, indexing into `U` with the `_path` key), and for the value we want to use the `Omit<U, "_path">` via [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) for dropping a key or keys from a type.

That's the basic approach, although it will tend to produce harder to read output types so you could change it to

```
type ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj<T extends readonly { _path: string }[]> =
  { [U in T[number] as U["_path"]]: 
    { [K in keyof U as K extends "_path" ? never : K]: U[K] } 
  } & {}
```

which computes an equivalent to `Omit` manually (using key remapping to filter out the `_path` by using `never` as the key) and [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with an empty object type to convince the compiler to display the type like `{x: {a: 1}, y: {b: 0}}` instead of `ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj<[{_path: "x", a: 1}, {_path: "y", b: 0}]>`.

---

Now we can write `blackBox()` to use that typing, possibly like:

```
const blackBox =
  <const T extends readonly { _path: string }[]>(arr: T) =>
    Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({ _path, ...rest }) => [_path, rest])) as
    ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj<T>;
```

This is a generic function which constrains `T` to the same thing as `ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj`.  I'm also giving it a [`const` type parameter modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) so that if you pass an array literal for `arr`, the compiler will treat it as if you used a `const` assertion on creation.

Anyway, the typing just takes an array of type `T` and returns a value of type `ObjWithPathArrayToPlainObj<T>`.  The actual implementation uses [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to assemble an array of key-value pairs to an object, and the key-value pairs are produced from `arr` by mapping them to the `_path` property and the rest of the object via [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).  That's probably the tersest way I can think of to write it, but you could expand it out to whatever meets your needs.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const resultObj = blackBox(startingArray);
/* const resultObj: {
    hello: { readonly prompt: "World"; };
    foo: { readonly bar: 4; };
    testing: { readonly value: 123; };
} */    
console.log(resultObj.hello.prompt.toUpperCase()) // "WORLD"

console.log(resultObj);
/* {
  "hello": { "prompt": "World" },
  "foo": { "bar": 4 },
  "testing": { "value": 123 }
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `resultObj` corresponds exactly to the output value, so the compiler knows, for example, that `resultObj.hello` has a string valued `prompt` property.

The `const T` modifier makes the following also work as desired with an inline array literal:

```
const resultObj2 = blackBox([
  { _path: "hello", prompt: "World" },
  { _path: "foo", bar: 4 },
  { _path: "testing", value: 123 },
]);
/* const resultObj2: {
    hello: { readonly prompt: "World"; };
    foo: { readonly bar: 4; };
    testing: { readonly value: 123; };
} */
```

If you remove it you'll get some too-wide type with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) since the compiler wouldn't keep track of `_path` being anything but `string`:

```
const blackBox = <T extends ⋯
// ------------> ^^^^ <--- removed const modifier

const resultObj2 = blackBox([
  { _path: "hello", prompt: "World" },
  { _path: "foo", bar: 4 },
  { _path: "testing", value: 123 },
]);
/* const resultObj2: {
  [x: string]: {
      prompt: string;
      bar?: undefined;
      value?: undefined;
  } | {
      bar: number;
      prompt?: undefined;
      value?: undefined;
  } | {
      value: number;
      prompt?: undefined;
      bar?: undefined;
  };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGAnKBLMBzAgox8CeMAvDANoBQMMA3jAPoAO8UAFgFwwBEzApgDa8gOAGhj1EIALb0o7DgHUQiXgBMOMAL5CK1OoxayAZiEEiARknYAWDVso0GTNpyjdoadMJgA3eLwCu3OwAjABMAMw2ZAC6MPAQMKCQUADcMAD0aTAAPAC0OTBg3NzKMCwo8YqlPAmS9Lwo3IgwzHEFIDAoytzwMADuLbDQiO7xDiyxiNxkZGkAVDVJcFBIqBjYuHjsk-DK4LwEJFTalNu7YPu6jrI8-ILJxzCnewRitTKcCkqq95rUD0-nAhjJwcIx3f7dM4XcyIKw-ERHSgnSHPS76ZyuVYee5Ix4owHeXwBYLhH4xWZpaZkKB4ejcGAAeVMACs5CgWAAFRzrfAAFRAHN48DQTOZWV5MG4AA8XGBlPEARd7HonEN3BoSFEAHxEbQ0EgAVQ6YBgvJIYD8ElMjSirQNJA4wI4USi7H1AGljTAANbcPAgAwwI2tT3S2XyzhOmAAfgK3C8jRg7HdrqDJBTGg02gAZNR1OlMrl8sy-NBYs00LAoO0IMwQL1Yib40SmMUCvAJFMyIky6YhcBvQAhEBS3WULI92ASsPcOUK-FKtGqqDDDAa7UACiQsNNAEoiFqHqLuMAoAA6AziCQAUTAK4aEC3ODPEng9A3G+VjhEZ9-kzL6j7oQOokMCIj-lAUS7vucRHiybKctyOB8gKQoiiy4pavc3bgGW-5+LwUCikQMB9vAA7DlKG4IMg7g8ngu73HMCx4a4BFESyboPDcAhuniOyoq8UjvPIigqBwqTqDiSJgnxioEDCcIaNJlAuG4GByQuBA+P4gQwKEYSST8MAUtMPYgLw3BngI6AbvhhGimePEgGeQnSGe1YGvQdKIAAwnE3AbtBBYfAyABKAAyAAiHA4ZAFlWTZdlsQ5LKMTM8yIpwzkcHxHBuVAuUfGJqiRJQoLGEVNAcDCRXWJo2gcGpWJVZwOkBEVBlZvmplxaxEDsaKIQkWRFEjhu5B2Eu1x8AIngFbInziWVOjAoYlVmBYMD1bYq0qrIzXuJ47V6V1DVQUx8yTniA2pcyIRcbizmaQJBILcVXwScpDyyTo8mkVtlhGQ8h0aX9WmErpJKGd9PWUmQYAdq4jDAPSg47H8lDXaNQ4jmOSLipKMqzhG-1fuiapruompak+O68kBh64pQx6nheV63verh0y+b4fuTzA-n+mIaIzpBgTdkHBbBzOMvB7LMFyLD0fygrCmAoqYdh0xY7hsD2Rx90jf2uNUZNSICzNtzzVe0iLSVagNbilucGCniKdtK1TWtGLqR4IgndDK0XdozHXQbQ2PUiJBSuwlPoKmWWy+98cqczMLRuwfhytwBhoMUae4idmcwNnXR54Uyhp-mAA+mOywDO4WlajSF0iBUl2Xuf51XDxF0S3CdznFcFw8tf17LgcFJa1qIG3lAd1nw89-PjdD+XK9j9JcPTOoQA)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. This helps me understand some things I did not understand previously, especially relating to the use of `const` and how it affects types; and I definitely have more clear understanding about what I can expect when dealing with generics.

Unfortunately, just by doing away with the generic type in the beginning, this solution won't apply to my use case. But it's invaluble to know what is required to achieve what I actually expected, and why my premise fell short. Thanks again.